# tinyxml load fails after using GetOpenFileName to retrieve xml filename

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, tinyxml

I was already using tinyxml 1 before I implemented the function GetOpenFileName in my code, so I know the load works whenever I give it a relative path or an absolute path.

I just don't understand why it doesn't work whenever the function GetOpenFileName executes first. I actually tried a few times to test and every time I executed that function, regardless of whether I used the filepath it gave me or not, tinyxml still wouldn't find the xml.

```
std::string tutName = getTutorialFilename();

if(tutName != "") {
    std::cout << "Before replacing: " << tutName << std::endl;

    boost::replace_all(tutName, "\\", "/");

    bool loadTutorial = tutorial->loadTutorialSteps(tutName);

    if(loadTutorial) {
        std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "failed: " << tutName << "to load" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The Function getTutorialFilename, which uses GetOpenFilename:

```
std::string getTutorialFilename() {
OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HWND hwnd;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "XML\0*.xml*\0All\0*.*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box. 

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) {
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
                    GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    (HANDLE) NULL);

    std::string tutorialFilename(szFile);

    return tutorialFilename;
}

return "";
```

}

I know it finds the tutorialFilename with no extra spaces as I've ran the debugger on that, but I still can't understand why tinyxml fails to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. TinyXML was outputting the error 13 - permission denied due to CreateFile blocking access to the file. I deleted that function because I don't need it.